# Breaking out of while loop using IR remote input

Tags: arduino-uno, led, ir

I'm trying to control a series of LEDs using an IR remote. I have a problem when I try to play a sequence with the LEDs where they all light up in a line and turn off accordingly. I loop through the sequence and I am trying to make it so the instant I press a button on the remote it breaks out of that sequence. The issue lies in the Flash(); function, I think. What can I do?

```
#include <boarddefs.h>
#include <IRremote.h>
#include <IRremoteInt.h>
#include <ir_Lego_PF_BitStreamEncoder.h>

int recvPin = 11;
IRrecv irrecv(recvPin);
decode_results results;

#define BUTTON_ON 0xF076C13B    // codes for different buttons on the remote
#define BUTTON_OFF 0xFF9186B7
#define BUTTON_R 0xE5CFBD7F
#define BUTTON_G 0x8C22657B
#define BUTTON_B 0x2A89195F
#define BUTTON_FLASH 0x35A9425F

int rLED = 5;
int gLED = 4;
int bLED = 3;
int stR = LOW;  // intital state of red LED
int stG = LOW;  // intital state of green LED
int stB = LOW;  // initial state of blue LED
int flash = false;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);   // Status message will be sent to PC at 9600 baud
  pinMode(rLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(gLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bLED, OUTPUT);

  irrecv.enableIRIn();
}

void Flash() {    // flashing function
  while (flash == false) {
    digitalWrite(rLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(gLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(bLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(rLED, HIGH);
    delay(75);
    digitalWrite(gLED, HIGH);
    delay(75);
    digitalWrite(bLED, HIGH);
    delay(75);
    digitalWrite(rLED, LOW);
    delay(75);
    digitalWrite(gLED, LOW);
    delay(75);
    digitalWrite(bLED, LOW);
    delay(75);
    stR = LOW;
    stG = LOW;
    stB = LOW;
    if (results.value == BUTTON_OFF)    // attempting to make it so when i press the OFF button on the remote,
    {                                   // the loop breaks/stops and I can go back to pressing any button on
      break;                            // the remote 
    }
  }
}



void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results))
  {
    if (results.value == BUTTON_ON)
    {
      digitalWrite(rLED, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(gLED, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(bLED, HIGH);
      stR = HIGH;
      stG = HIGH;
      stB = HIGH;
    }
    if (results.value == BUTTON_OFF)
    {
      digitalWrite(rLED, LOW);
      digitalWrite(gLED, LOW);
      digitalWrite(bLED, LOW);
      stR = LOW;
      stG = LOW;
      stB = LOW;
    }
    if (results.value == BUTTON_R)
    {
      digitalWrite(rLED, !stR);
      stR = !stR;
    }
    if (results.value == BUTTON_G)
    {
      digitalWrite(gLED, !stG);
      stG = !stG;
    }
    if (results.value == BUTTON_B)
    {
      digitalWrite(bLED, !stB);
      stB = !stB;
    }
    if (results.value == BUTTON_FLASH)
    {
      Flash();    // calling flash func
    }
    irrecv.resume();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace delay with millis in `Flash()`.

You do this by making every delay it's own state and give each state a number. Then inside `flash` you check which state you are in to set the LEDs and how long you have been in it to trigger the next state.

```
boolean flashing = false;
int flashingState = -1;
long nextFlashingState = 0;

void Flash() {    // flashing function
  if(!flashing ){
    flashingState =-1;
    return;
  }

  long ms = millis();
  switch(flashingState ){
  case -1:
    flashingState =0;
    nextflashingState = ms+75; //init "timer"
    //fallthrough
  case 0:
    digitalWrite(rLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(gLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(bLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(rLED, HIGH);
    if(nextflashingState < ms){
        flashingState =1;
        nextflashingState +=75;
    }
    break;
 case 1:
    digitalWrite(gLED, HIGH);
    if(nextflashingState < ms){
        flashingState = 2;
        nextflashingState +=75;
    }
    break;
 case 2:
    digitalWrite(bLED, HIGH);
    if(nextflashingState < ms){
        flashingState = 3;
        nextflashingState +=75;
    }
    break;
  case 3:
    digitalWrite(rLED, LOW);
    if(nextflashingState < ms){
        flashingState = 4;
        nextflashingState +=75;
    }
    break;
  case 4:
    digitalWrite(gLED, LOW);
    if(nextflashingState < ms){
        flashingState = 5;
        nextflashingState +=75;
    }
    break;
  case 5:
    digitalWrite(bLED, LOW);
    if(nextflashingState < ms){
        flashingState = 0;
        nextflashingState +=75;
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

I used state `-1` as the init state to start the timer, the case block will fall through to the next case. The `millis()` function returns the number of milliseconds since the arduino booted up (it overflows every ~1.5 months). So when I start a timer I set the the `nextFlashingState` to the time when it should start the next state.

Then in loop you call it every time.

```
void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results))
  {
    if (results.value == BUTTON_ON)
    {
      digitalWrite(rLED, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(gLED, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(bLED, HIGH);
      stR = HIGH;
      stG = HIGH;
      stB = HIGH;
    }
    if (results.value == BUTTON_OFF)
    {
        flashing =false;
      digitalWrite(rLED, LOW);
      digitalWrite(gLED, LOW);
      digitalWrite(bLED, LOW);
      stR = LOW;
      stG = LOW;
      stB = LOW;
    }
    if (results.value == BUTTON_R)
    {
      digitalWrite(rLED, !stR);
      stR = !stR;
    }
    if (results.value == BUTTON_G)
    {
      digitalWrite(gLED, !stG);
      stG = !stG;
    }
    if (results.value == BUTTON_B)
    {
      digitalWrite(bLED, !stB);
      stB = !stB;
    }
    if (results.value == BUTTON_FLASH)
    {
        flashing =true;
    }
    irrecv.resume();
  }

  Flash();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't really understand your code, however, I uploaded it and it doesn't seem to do what I wanted it to do. When I press the flash button on the remote, it still flashes endlessly, but now when I press something on the remote the lights do kinda respond to it but keep flashing endlessly.

Comment: it will stop flashing when you press off. If you add `flashing =false;` to the other if blocks then flashing will stop when that button is pressed

Comment: Alright, thanks, it works! I wonder how I will make it work with more complicated sequences but for now I do wanna understand what you did there in the `void Flash()` function and anything else you added cause I am a beginner and if you could possibly refer me to some website where I can learn more about this I would greatly appreciate it :)

Comment: @EdD I edited my answer to explain a bit how you would go about replacing delay with millis